# 'Invalid Syntax' error for connection.send function with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh

Setting up a code block to interact with a Checkpoint firewall and I'm getting a random 'Invalid Syntax' error when I try to run the script.

If I run the commands one by one in the python shell it works just fine.

Full Code is at https://pastebin.com/zKVSXsQs

Here's the code block that's getting the error:

```
    connection.send("clish" + "\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    connection.send("delete vpn tunnel" + vpnt + "\n")
    time.sleep(3)
    connection.send("save config" + "\n")
    time.sleep(3)
    #####  This next line is what errors out
    connection.send("add vpn tunnel" + vpnt + "type numbered local 10.50." + subnet ".4 remote 10.50." + subnet + ".1" + "\n")
    ##### End of erring code
    time.sleep(3)
    connection.send("save config" + "\n")
    session.close()
    exit()
```

Here's the exact error:

```
connection.send("add vpn tunnel" + vpnt + "type numbered local 10.50." + subnet ".4 remote 10.50." + subnet + ".1" + "\n")

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Missing `+` between `subnet`  and `".4 remote 10.10"`

Comment: Using the `+` operator on strings is considered bad practice in Python. Alternatives are shown at https://pyformat.info/ .

Comment: btw, if you really had posted the *exact* error, you would have included the `^` which would have at least been in the region of the error.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for the + sign catch.   And I tried to copy/paste the error, but the carret doesn't format correctly on this site.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the info.  I'm still very new at Python.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes it does:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\YES_IT_DOES.py", line 8
    connection.send("add vpn tunnel" + vpnt + "type numbered local 10.50." + subnet ".4 remote 10.50." + subnet + ".1" + "\n")
                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Scroll sideways ---> to see the caret `^`